# how to Join five Tables with one another dependency in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want to join five tables in SQL server. The sequence as given below. Logic should be
Table1  >>>>Key :  ID >>>>  Table_A & Table_B (If Table1.Status = ABC then Table_A else Table_B  ) >>> Key : NUMBER >>> Table2 >>> Key : Number + Item_No >>> Table3

Please help if below code could work.

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM 
TABLE1
LEFT JOIN (CASE WHEN status = 'ABC' THEN Table_A ELSE Table_B END ) X ON (Table1.ID = X.ID)
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON (X.NUMBER = Table2.NUMBER)
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON (Table3.CONCAT(NUMBER + Item_No) = Table2.CONCAT(NUMBER + Item_No))
```

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I would advise you not to join on concatenated values. if you want to to join and two pieces of data then use two predicates. t3.Number = t2.number AND t3.ItemNo = t2.ItemNo. This is not only more accurate it is also SARGable which that concatenation is not.

Comment: You can't use a conditional CASE WHEN construct immediately after JOIN. Either you JOIN, or you don't... CASE WHEN can only produce a single value (e.g. INT, VARCHAR), not an entire table.

Comment: And CASE is an expression, meaning it is used to return a scalar value. You can't use CASE to decide which table to join to. That will never work like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Q.*, T2.ItemNo, T2.Product, T3.Connection
FROM (
     SELECT T1.ID, CASE WHEN T1.Status = 'ABC'
                        THEN TA.Number
                        ELSE TB.Number
                   END as Number
     FROM Table1 T1
     LEFT JOIN TableA TA
       ON T1.ID = TA.ID
     LEFT JOIN TableB TB
       ON T1.ID = TB.ID
     ) as Q
JOIN Table2 T2
  ON Q.Number = T2.Number
JOIN Table3 T3
  ON T2.ItemNo = T3.ItemNo
```

Comment: btw dont know why Table2 and Table3 arent merge together